# Trace32 Execute script when program stops

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

Is there a way to execute a script every time the program stops?
I need to do something like this:

```
Var.Set \myvar=list[Id]
```

where list and Id are variables from the program.

However when  the Id changes `\myvar` doesn't change, it remains with the value which corresponds to the old Id.

This is why I want to run a script that does that command every time a program stops from running.

Answer (score 1):

To run a script every time the program stops use the command ON or GLOBALON. ON is suitable when there is still an active PRACTICE script controlling your test case. GLOBALON is suitable if you want a reaction on an event until you disable it again.

General syntax is:

```
ON|GLOBALON <event> <action>
```

where "event" can be PBREAK for "program-break" and "action" can be "DO <script.cmm>" to execute an individual script on the event.

Putting all together you get:

```
GLOBALON PBREAK DO syncmyvar.cmm
```

where script syncmyvar.cmm contains your command `Var.Set \myvar=list[Id]`

To disable the event handler on a program break use

```
GLOBALON PBREAK inherit
```

---

If I understand your use case correctly, you'd like to execute the command `Var.Set \myvar=list[Id]` every time `Id` changes. In this case I would consider to use a write-breakpoint with a command action. E.g. like this:

```
Var.Break.Set Id /Write /CMD "Var.Set \myvar=list[Id]" /RESUME
```

However this gives a quite different behavior: With this breakpoint, you application gets stopped shortly for every write access to Id and \myvar is always in sync with Id, while with `GLOBALON PBREAK DO syncmyvar.cmm` the variable \myvar gets only updated when the application completely stops.